# Fresh WAS-CE installation gives nothing but "HTTP 400 'bad request'"?

Tags: java, ubuntu, websphere-ce

I apologise in advance for something I'm expecting is a horrifyingly noob-question.

I decided to try out developing web-applications in Java, using IBM's WAS-CE platform. I've never worked with this platform before, nor any other platforms for running Java web applications (I've been using php for all my web projects).

Now, I downloaded the community edition of WAS, and installed it on my laptop (Ubuntu 8.10, 64bit, java-6-sun-1.6.0.10). It worked like a charm. I proceeded to install WAS-CE on my development server (Ubuntu 8.10, 32bit, java-6-sun-1.6.0.07), and it seemed fine.

However when I connect to the server (and it does bind to all ports I expect it to), when firefox requests a page (haven't tried other browser) the server returns a HTTP 400 - "bad request". If a connect manually to the server and give it a pure "GET /\n\n", it just closes the connection, while doing that works fine on my laptop.

The only difference I can spot between the two installations is the older Java version (1.6.0.07 is the current one in the ubuntu repositories though), and the 32 bit processor. Is there such a great difference between those java versions that WebSphere would actually fail?

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the WAS CE setup troubleshooting docs. 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.0/en/setup-troubleshooting.html

I'm not sure if that will help or not, but you could also try using an IBM JDK instead of Sun. 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.0/en/installing-an-application-server.html